# Does Facebook's ProfilePictureView return default profile pic for test users?

Tags: android, facebook

Facebook's `ProfilePictureView` has a method `setProfileId(String_of_ID)` which returns the picture of the user with the given ID. For my test users, the image returned is a default image despite having set one of the user's profile picture manually. Is this because test users do not have a public profiles? i.e. `facebook.com/test_user_id` returns a 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the image I set for the test user **does** appear. Unsure as to why it didn't initially as no code has been changed - just a rerun of the app a while later worked.